# Listview not refresh when any property of a list item changes

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Listview not refresh when any changes on a listview items property
here is my PageModel:

```
Public MyPageModel()
{
// populating listview data
ListData=PopulateData();

ObservableCollection<MyClass> _listData = new ObservableCollection<MyClass>();
public ObservableCollection<MyClass> ListData
        {
            get { return _listData; }
            set
            {
                _listData = value;
               RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
}
foreach(MyClass item in ListData)
{
  if(item.id==2)
  {
    item.Name="UpdatedName"
  }
}
```

Inside XAML:

```
 <ListView ItemSource="{Bindind ListData}">
      ..............
    </ListView>
```

after changing item details it will not update the listview itemsource

Answer (score 2):

Did you added the property notify change in 'MyClass' as well?
ex:

```
private string _name;
public string Name
{
    get { return _name; }
    set
    {
        _name = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: No i dont,actually I have created MyClass outside my PageModel :(

Comment: That's ok. still you can inherit INotifyPropertyChanged interface and you can update the properties..

Comment: After adding  RaisePropertyChanged() in my Properties,its working fine.Thanks :)

Comment: Great. Welcome :-)

Comment: If the solution is working, mark it is answer so that others can benefit from it.